# Using datasource on wildfly shutdown

Tags: java, spring, jboss, datasource, wildfly

I'm trying to perform some updates on the database when the Wildfly server is being shut down.

Unfortunately, it seems that the datasource I use to update the database is being closed before the application is undeployed ...

Here is the relevant code :

```
@PreDestroy
public void shutdown()
{
    logger.debug("|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| Closing GatewayDAO");
    System.out.println("Closing GatewayDAO ");

    Session session = getSession();
    Query query =  session.createQuery("UPDATE Gateway gw SET gw.status = 0, gw.lastActivity = NOW()");
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

As you see, I use Spring destroy detection.

In the Wildfly console:

```
[...]

[WF] 11:58:22,794 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/RfBerry]

[...]


[WF] 11:58:23,500 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 271) Closing GatewayDAO
[WF] 11:58:23,550 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 271) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
[WF] 11:58:23,550 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 271) javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000470: You are trying to use a connection factory that has been shut down: java:jboss/datasources/RfBerry
[WF] 11:58:23,556 WARN  [org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 271) Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'gatewayDAOImpl': org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

I don't know if it is possible to tell wildfly to close datasource after application undeployement.

Note: the code works when I just undeploy the application and leave the server opened.

Comment: Try inject the datasource to generate the dependency to this. Eg. `@Resource(lookup = "java:/app/datasource") DataSource dataSource;`

Comment: I already tried that, it didn't solve my problem, the session is still closed if I try to send sql queries

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with `@DependsOn("datasource")` .

Comment: didn't work, same error, I don't know if the problem is on my application or if spring just works this way  ...